# UICollection cell issues between 4inch and 4.7inch iphones

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]
I am looking for a grid and I am using an UICollectionView. I want this grid 10x10. My cell is 28x28.

I have an inferred view controller, so I can set it out and it runs on both devices.

When i do

println (collection view.frame)
On the iPhone 5 and 6 simulator , I get 0.0,0.0,320,568 
which is fine.

On the iPhone 6 I get the 10 across but on the iPhone 5 i get 8 across.

The code I am using splits the width by 10 and assigns the size for the cell - like so :

```
  let width = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView!.frame) / 10
        let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
```

any ideas why I am still getting different amounts of cells vertically on the devices ?

Comment: Where are you running this code? In viewDidLoad? viewWillAppear? etc.

Comment: yup viewDidLoad and its not doing anything useful!!!

Comment: Looks like you want your collection view to be full screen? In that case, try calculating width based on view.bounds instead of collectionView.frame. During viewDidLoad, the collectionView's frame probably hasn't been adjusted yet to fit the screen size, but the view bounds is.

Comment: I don't want it to be full screen. The UIView is the full size and the uiCollectionview is about 60 points before the nav bar.... So thats why I want the size of the collection view and not the size of the UIView

Comment: You also need to set `minimumLineSpacing` and `minimumInterItemSpacing` (of the `layout`) to `0` if you don't want any space between items. And `sectionInset` to `UIEdgeInsetZero` too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to fit your app to iPhone 6/6+ by adding the "Launch Screen File" in the project's target page (under the icon and launch images). This get you the real screen size on iPhone6 which is 375,647.

Second, what you did is to define the cell size as 32 pix width without considering the space between cells and section insets. If you want 10 exactly cells that will also fill out the whole screen width you need to set minimumInterItemSpacing and sectionInset to 0 too.

Try changing "let layout..." to "var layout = " too.